# Ignore case in string split C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string builder and I want to ignore the case(lower or uppercase) of textbox2.Text when spliting.

Here's the line of code which I think the adjustment must be made.

```
String[] subStrings = e.Item.Text.Split(new String[] { textBox2.Text }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

StringSplitOptions has only two option which is None and RemoveEmptyEntries

My full program would be if I type: "steph" , the text "Steph" in "Stephen" will be highlighted even the textbox2.text first character is lowercase.

My full code:

```
String[] subStrings = element.Text.Split(new String[] { textBox2.Text }, StringSplitOptions.);
if (subStrings.Count() >= 2)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(subStrings[0]);
    sb.Append("<color=#0193C6>" + textBox2.Text + "</color>");
    sb.Append(subStrings[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < subStrings.Count(); i++)
        sb.Append(textBox2.Text + subStrings[i]);
    element.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Use [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) instead

Comment: `ToLowercase()` the string before splitting?

Comment: You should retitle. This has nothing to do with StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

Try Using Regex.Split. For e.g.

```
Regex.Split(textBox2.Text, "pattern", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Actually I already tried that but thats not I want.
It doesnt work I have to put the whole pattern to highlight the pattern

Pattern: Stephen Curry
textbox2 = stephen curry
and the pattern transform to textbox2 which is not I want

I want is when I type: steph . The pattern will not change and just highlight the Steph :)

Comment: Have you tried using the another answer using LowerCase?                 string elementString = element.Text;
String[] subStrings = elementString.ToLower().Split(new[] { textBox2.Text.ToLower() }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Answer (score 0):

Try converting both the element and the textbox.Text ToLower().

```
string elementString = element.Text;
            String[] subStrings = elementString.ToLower().Split(new[] { textBox2.Text.ToLower() }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (subStrings.Count() >= 2)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(subStrings[0]);
                sb.Append("<color=#0193C6>" + textBox2.Text + "</color>");
                sb.Append(subStrings[1]);
                for (int i = 2; i < subStrings.Count(); i++)
                    sb.Append(textBox2.Text + subStrings[i]);
                element.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
```